# Spinbox .get() between classes tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently trying to create a loop where the number of entry boxes created is based on the value of a Spinbox, which is in a different class to the loop. I understand that my code is broken but I'm not sure where to go from here. The spinbox variable is in the class StudentAmount2 and the entry boxes loop is in the class ClassLists3. Cheers.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tk import *
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)

student_no = 0

class app(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        
        container.pack(side="top", fil="both", expand=True)
        
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {}
        
        for F in (HomePage1,StudentAmount2,ClassList3,Subjects4):
        
            frame = F(container, self)
            
            self.frames[F] = frame
            
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(HomePage1)
        
    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()
    
    def set_number(self):
        student_no = 0
        student_no += Amount.get()
        
class HomePage1(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Percentage from Grade")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0,pady=10, padx=10)
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Begin", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StudentAmount2))
        button.grid(row=1, column=0)
        #home page is complete

class StudentAmount2(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Number of Students")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        SetValue = tk.StringVar()
        SetValue.set("0")
        Amount = tk.Spinbox(self, from_=1, to=30)
        Amount.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10)
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ClassList3))
        button.grid(row=3, column=0)
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Set", command=lambda: controller.set_number())
        button1.grid(row=2, column=0)
    

class ClassList3(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        class_list_label = tk.Label(self, text="Class List")
        class_list_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Subjects4))
        button1.grid(row=31, column=0, columnspan=2)
        
        for y in range(0,2):
            for x in range(0, student_no):
                student = tk.Entry(self)
                student.grid(row=x+1, column=y, padx=5)
  
class Subjects4(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Back",command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ClassList3))
        button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        
root = app()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Then you need to create a function in `StudentAmount2` that returns the current value of the spin box.  You can add a function to `app` that allows access to the other fields.  `ClassList3` gets the parent object, so it can ask the app for the `StudentAmount2` instance and fetch the field value.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm trying to create the function in StudentAmount2, but Amount.get() is either not defined or I cannot add add its value to the student_no variable

Comment: Two problems.  You are not storing your control instances anywhere, so you need `self.Amount = Amount` after you create the spinbox, then you can do `self.frames[StudentAmount2].Amount.get()` in the app class.

Comment: Thanks so much that has set the value of student_no correctly. This will be the last question - the value of student_no is taken once the program is initialised, so the value of student_no is what the initial value of the spinbox is set to. How do I update the value of student_no before I run the for loop to create the specified number of entry boxes?

Comment: You read the spinbox immediately before you create the entry boxes.  It does no good to read it before then.